# iOS Table View XIB layout issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, xib

I have declared x3 `UITableView`'s in Xcode **XIB interface builder**:

[image]

Then I ran current `UIViewController` in **iPad Air iOS Simulator**:

[image]

As you see, top cell of the first `UITableView` view differs to second one / third one.

Why is that so?

How to make these `UITableView`'look like the same?

Comment: did you set the tableviews' datasource to be the viewcontroller? and did you implement the numberofrows and cellforrowatindexpath method?

Comment: Nope. It is just interface builder. It is not connected with data source yet

Comment: ok. i could reproduce that behaviour. looks the same for me! but as soon as you implement the required datasource / delegate methods you should be ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i got it. override the init method like the following:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

you have to take care of the insets yourself since this automatic property can only handle the inset for the **first** subview in the hierarchy.

Comment: Can I provide this option in XIB interface builder?

Comment: only when using storyboards.

Comment: However, this option makes all my view controllers act like second and third one (ignore navigation bar). Is it possible, that every table view would act like first one?

Answer (score 1):

for the inset problem create those properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewLeft;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewMiddle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewRight;
```

and then try the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    self.tableViewLeft.contentInset = inset;
    self.tableViewMiddle.contentInset = inset;
    self.tableViewRight.contentInset = inset;
}
```

Comment: Both of your answers are correct for me, even if I can mark only one of them. Thank you!